# Polkadot 29 update - try-runtime feature (trait bounds error)

Tags: runtime, upgrade, try-runtime

We are doing upgrade to polkadot version 29. Everything works fine until we run the command

```
cargo build -r --features try-runtime
```

we got error trait bounds. In this version there was change from **execute_block_no_check** to **try_execute_block**

Here we change to this in [runtime](https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/blob/develop-v0.9.29/runtime/mangata-rococo/src/lib.rs#L1438)

and here is the error we see in the [console](https://gist.github.com/devdanco/70e3556e04a15ad49ede6fe1ecfb2164)

Are we missing something ? We could not find any issue.

Here is the link to [repo](https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/tree/develop-v0.9.29)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The auto-generated implementation for the `TryState` trait is feature gated behind `try-runtime`.
This requires all pallets to support `try-runtime` as well.
You can try it out for a single pallet by putting this line above the error-producing `try_execute_block`:

```rust
<frame_system::Pallet<Runtime> as frame_support::traits::TryState<_>>::try_state();
```

This will produce an error claiming that `frame_system::Pallet` does not implement `TryState`. It can be fixed by adding `frame-system/try-runtime`, `frame-support/try-runtime` and `frame-executive/try-runtime` to the `try-runtime` feature list of the runtime `Cargo.toml`.
Sadly it looks like some pallets that you have deployed do currently not support that feature.
They need to be updated to support the feature and propagate it to all dependencies.

The feature system of Rust is really annoying when it comes to this. We are slowly cleaning up Substrate and remove any feature-bleed; eg https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11976 and  https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12341.
In this case we case it is a bit unfortunate that the pallets all need to support it. If you are really lucky you can try removing [this](https://github.com/mangata-finance/substrate/blob/mangata-dev-v0.9.29/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/hooks.rs#L207) line and do some feature hacking to maybe get it working without that.
But then you have non-production hooks in production code; also not good.

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your help. This will solve our problem.

Comment: I am facing similar issue, could you guys please help me understand what is still missing in my working progress PR https://github.com/zeitgeistpm/zeitgeist/pull/887
?
Here are the errors I am facing https://gist.github.com/vivekvpandya/69d09d47d0da83f95a04fe57fbbddf99

Comment: Could be that you are not passing the `try-runtime` feature to `frame-executive` in all `Cargo.toml` files. The `zrml/court/Cargo.toml` for example is missing it. Not sure if that is the only error but if could be responsible.

Comment: Thanks @OliverTale-Yazdi I tried to make it work as https://github.com/mangata-finance/mangata-node/tree/develop-v0.9.29 however there seems something wrong I am getting errors as shown at https://gist.github.com/vivekvpandya/2883f4249457322b7e233e7f4b821c0a
looks like two different version of frame_support is being compiled and something is not good.

Comment: ok one pallet didn't have the try-runtime feature enabled inside the runtime cargo toml. thanks for the help here

Comment: So all pallets which have upgrades, also must enable try-runtime to compile. If pallet has not upgrade, it will be ok?

Comment: Rust features must always be propagated to all pallets that expose them. Otherwise there will be issues. So just forward the try-runtime feature to all pallets that have it and you should be fine.